# How to display values of 1 column with respect to particular values present in some other column in Excel sheet in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a sample document from my Excel sheet (I couldn't upload the screenshot of the Excel sheet, so I tried to make a similar table form with 4 attributes/columns). I want to write code in Python so that I can count how many times any movie name from column 1 is present for a particular value in column 4.

#### Sample data:

For ex. *Dead poet society* is present for A, D & E. *The longest ride* is present for C & twice for D.

```
+====================+====================+============+=========+
|      Column1       |      Column2       |  Column3   | Column4 |
+====================+====================+============+=========+
| Dead poet society  | Julia Roberts      | London     | A       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Before sunrise     | Sandra Bullock     | Paris      | A       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Finding Dory       | Emma Stone         | Rome       | A       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Blood diamond      | Anne Hathaway      | Canada     | A       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| A Beautiful mind   | Amanda Seyfried    | Scotland   | B       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Blood diamond      | Anne Hathaway      | Canada     | B       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Before sunrise     | Sandra Bullock     | Paris      | B       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| The longest ride   | Reese Witherspoon  | Denmark    | C       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Marley and me      | Jennifer Aniston   | Germany    | C       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| The longest ride   | Reese Witherspoon  | Denmark    | D       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Dead poet society  | Julia Roberts      | London     | D       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Remember me        | Natalie Portman    | Bulgaria   | D       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Inception          | Kate Winslet       | Sweden     | D       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| The longest ride   | Reese Witherspoon  | Denmark    | D       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Gone with the wind | Scarlett Johansson | Brazil     | E       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Dead poet society  | Julia Roberts      | London     | E       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Before sunrise     | Sandra Bullock     | Paris      | E       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| Midnight in Paris  | Meg Ryan           | Queensland | E       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
```

#### Code so far:

Here is the code I have used but it is not helping.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('sample_docu.xlsx')
cells = s.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
cells_2 = s.cell_value(rowx=2, colx=3) 
count=0                            
if cells in cells_2:
    count=count+1
    print('Count={}'.format(count))
```

Comment: You haven't listed anything you have tried. Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Comment: Actually I am new here. I agree with you but I don't know how to solve this issue. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: Welcome! It is great that you found this site, and are hoping it proves to be useful. However, you aren't going to get much help if you haven't shown what you have tried. Take a look here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have helped by providing you the table formatting for your example. I cannot help with the python code though.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have provided the code I have used.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `sentiment-analysis` - please do not spam the tags (edited & removed)

Answer (score 1):

Noting that your code attempt, imported pandas, I will show how to do that using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), since it makes this quite straight forward.

#### Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df.groupby(['Title', 'Category']).size())
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# build some sample data    
sample_df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
     Title               Name                City        Category 
     Dead poet society   Julia Roberts       London      A       
     Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock      Paris       A       
     Finding Dory        Emma Stone          Rome        A       
     Blood diamond       Anne Hathaway       Canada      A       
     A Beautiful mind    Amanda Seyfried     Scotland    B       
     Blood diamond       Anne Hathaway       Canada      B       
     Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock      Paris       B       
     The longest ride    Reese Witherspoon   Denmark     C       
     Marley and me       Jennifer Aniston    Germany     C       
     The longest ride    Reese Witherspoon   Denmark     D       
     Dead poet society   Julia Roberts       London      D       
     Remember me         Natalie Portman     Bulgaria    D       
     Inception           Kate Winslet        Sweden      D       
     The longest ride    Reese Witherspoon   Denmark     D       
     Gone with the wind  Scarlett Johansson  Brazil      E       
     Dead poet society   Julia Roberts       London      E       
     Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock      Paris       E       
     Midnight in Paris   Meg Ryan            Queensland  E"""),
                 header=1)

# save the data to an excel file, just so we can read it back in directly
sample_df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
print(sample_df)

# read the dataframe from excel
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# show the number of time each title is in the category
print(df.groupby(['Title', 'Category']).size())
```

#### Results:

```
                 Title                Name        City Category
0    Dead poet society       Julia Roberts      London        A
1       Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock       Paris        A
2         Finding Dory          Emma Stone        Rome        A
3        Blood diamond       Anne Hathaway      Canada        A
4     A Beautiful mind     Amanda Seyfried    Scotland        B
5        Blood diamond       Anne Hathaway      Canada        B
6       Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock       Paris        B
7     The longest ride   Reese Witherspoon     Denmark        C
8        Marley and me    Jennifer Aniston     Germany        C
9     The longest ride   Reese Witherspoon     Denmark        D
10   Dead poet society       Julia Roberts      London        D
11         Remember me     Natalie Portman    Bulgaria        D
12           Inception        Kate Winslet      Sweden        D
13    The longest ride   Reese Witherspoon     Denmark        D
14  Gone with the wind  Scarlett Johansson      Brazil        E
15   Dead poet society       Julia Roberts      London        E
16      Before sunrise      Sandra Bullock       Paris        E
17   Midnight in Paris            Meg Ryan  Queensland        E

Title               Category
A Beautiful mind    B           1
Before sunrise      A           1
                    B           1
                    E           1
Blood diamond       A           1
                    B           1
Dead poet society   A           1
                    D           1
                    E           1
Finding Dory        A           1
Gone with the wind  E           1
Inception           D           1
Marley and me       C           1
Midnight in Paris   E           1
Remember me         D           1
The longest ride    C           1
                    D           2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but in jupyter notebook it is saying "name 'StringIO' is not defined" and hence the code isn't running.

Comment: @SanchariGhosh, I added the missing import

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. It is working fine. Could you please explain this line to me: "sample_df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO......."

Comment: That is just test code that allows me to easily setup to run with your data.  `read_fwf` would normally be used to import from a text file.  But instead I fake a text file with StringIO.  Read into a dataframe, then write the dataframe as an excel file.  Only then do we get to the code of interest.

Comment: Also I am trying to read the excel sheet and then do the required operations, not by explicitly providing the data to the code.

Comment: Yes: please read carefully.  That is why I started at the top with the two lines that actually matter.  Those two line (under code) are the last two lines in the test.  Everything before those two line in the test code, are **ONLY** because you did not provide your excel data in a form I could use.  So I was forced to create data this way.  And yes, you only need TWO lines of code to do what you need.

Comment: Oh ok...I got it. Thanks a lot.